# How to utilize a boolean method, which returns more than 2 values

Tags: java, methods, boolean, collision-detection

This method returns true, false, and another value.

```
public boolean Intersection (Circle circle, Rectangle rectangle) {

... // test something
... return true;
... // test another thing
... return false;
... 
... return xCornerDistSq + yCornerDistSq <= maxCornerDistSq; //Third return value
}
```

This is a 2D game, where a ball is supposed to bounce off of a rectangle, including the edges of the rectangle. The third return value, which I linked above, is supposed to detect collision between the ball and the edges of the rectangle. The problem is, I don't know how to utilize it in my code once I call the method.

What I currently have is this

This is the full code of the method:

```
        public boolean Intersection (Circle circle, Rectangle rectangle) {
            double cx = Math.abs(circle.getLayoutX() - rectangle.getLayoutX() - rectangle.getWidth() / 2);
            double xDist = rectangle.getWidth() / 2 + circle.getRadius();

            if (cx > xDist) { return false; }

            double cy = Math.abs(circle.getLayoutY() - rectangle.getLayoutY() - rectangle.getHeight() / 2) ;
            double yDist = rectangle.getHeight() / 2 + circle.getRadius();

            if (cy > yDist) { return false; }

            if (cx <= rectangle.getWidth() / 2 || cy <= rectangle.getHeight() / 2) { return true; }

            double xCornerDist = cx - rectangle.getWidth() / 2;
            double yCornerDist = cy - rectangle.getHeight() / 2;
            double xCornerDistSq = xCornerDist * xCornerDist;
            double yCornerDistSq = yCornerDist * yCornerDist;
            double maxCornerDistSq = circle.getRadius() * circle.getRadius();
            return xCornerDistSq + yCornerDistSq <= maxCornerDistSq;
        }
```

So, how do I go about implementing it when I call the function? I want my ball to bounce off of the edges too, but I don't know how to call it by using this method.

What I currently have is this:

```
                boolean intersection = Intersection(circle1, rect1);
                if (intersection == true) {
                    double x = (rect1.getLayoutX() + rect1.getWidth()  / 2) - (circle1.getLayoutX() + circle1.getRadius());
                    double y = (rect1.getLayoutY() + rect1.getHeight() / 2) - (circle1.getLayoutY() + circle1.getRadius());
                    if (Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) {
                        c1SpeedX = -c1SpeedX;
                    } else {
                        c1SpeedY = -c1SpeedY;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: True, false and maybe? You could write an enum.

Comment: The code shown _will_ return just two possible values. The last line will return either true or false. If you need to return more than two values, then a different type must be used - `boolean` won't work

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to do that. Can you provide a code example please?

Comment: An enumeration might work, you can also return an int, -1, 0 and 1.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, that's interesting. So I don't need to add an enum or do anything like that, as the third value will be returned as true or false either way. Then why is my code not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may return method execution result as code represented for example as `int`. Your code will look something like this:

```
public int Intersection (Circle circle, Rectangle rectangle) {

... // test something
... return 0;
... // test another thing
... return 1;
... 
... return (xCornerDistSq + yCornerDistSq <= maxCornerDistSq) ? 2 : 3;
}
```

Instead of `int` of cource you may return enum. For example you may create and use the following enum as method's return value:

```
public enum ReturnCode {
  CODE1,
  CODE2,
  CODE3,
  CODE4,
  CODEN;
}
```

Code will look like this:

```
public ReturnCode Intersection (Circle circle, Rectangle rectangle) {

... // test something
... return ReturnCode.CODE1;
... // test another thing
... return ReturnCode.CODE2;
... 
... return (xCornerDistSq + yCornerDistSq <= maxCornerDistSq) ? ReturnCode.CODE3 : ReturnCode.CODE4;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A "hypothetical" enum might look like

```
public enum Ternary {
  TRUE, FALSE, MAYBE;
}
```

Comment: If the MAYBE is caused by something like "no decision possible", you could also use Boolean and return true, false or null. But I think the asker doesn't realize his code only returns two different values as it is now.

Comment: What are the parentheses for? Just write `public enum Ternary { TRUE, FALSE, MAYBE; }`

Comment: They just call default constructor which is inherited from Object. It is actually the same.

Comment: @ferrerverck They were redundant (and immaterial to the answer). I sometimes use an explicit `super()` in my constructors too... it is a little sloppy.